# Read/write imag files by lines or by pixels using Java

Tags: java, image, file-io

I have a specific object with image data. And I want read/write images (in BMP, JPEG and PNG formats) to this object.

Of course, I can read/write image into/from `BufferedImage` and then copy/paste pixels into/from my object. **But, I want to do it more faster without intermediate objects!**

How can I perform it over standard Java library or throw other Java library?

P.S.:
I know [pngj](http://code.google.com/p/pngj/) library that allow read PNG images by lines. Maybe you know same libraries for BMP, JPEG (or for all of them: BMP, JPEG, PNG)?

Comment: Why do you want to do this faster and without intermediate objects? Is there an actual bottleneck in your program caused by how the Java library reads in images?

Comment: When I using intermediate objects I spend time for unnecessary copy of information in memory and for memory allocation. Because of that, I think that read/write data directly is better.

Comment: Is this when *you* use intermediate objects or when the Java  library does? `ImageIO` does not needlessly copy information in memory. Most of its information sharing will take place in the form of copying a pointer, which does not take long at all.

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just have the `BufferedImage` in your `Object`? `BufferedImage` isn't all that bad. Otherwise, you will need to use something like `BufferedImage` to convert the image file into pixels, and then read the `BufferedImage` into something like an `int[]` array of pixels, but it still requires `BufferedImage` in the middle, and this would slow things down by adding an extra loop to read over and store the pixels.

Is there a reason why `BufferedImage` isn't suitable for your purpose?

Comment: Some times I no need all image (part of in will be enough) and I see no reason read all image into memory. And I think, that if exists simple way read image by line or by pixel I should try it.

But maybe you right -- simplest way is using `BufferedImage`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do all the reading by yourself, you can just open the file with a stream and read it into an array, but you would need to work your way through the whole structure of the file (headers etc...) if you are working with compressed formats you'd have to work on that too.

Best would be to use imageio to load/write your files and I don't believe there is a lot of overhead coming from the read/write of your images.
Also if you expect to do some heavy work on the images, know that BufferedImages can be hardware accelerated which will improve performance a lot.